# New page in menu

Tags: android, android-layout, android-optionsmenu

I want to make a new layout for a menu item. For example the menu has the items: <kbd>About</kbd> and <kbd>Exit</kbd>. When I click the item <kbd>About</kbd>, I want it to go to a new page that shows the credits.

I have made something like this, but I get an error, any help?

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.xsi_zero, menu);

    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch(item.getItemId()) {
    case R.id.aboutMenu:
        setContentView(R.layout.about);
        break;
    case R.id.exitGame:
        XsiZero.this.finish();
        break;
    }

    return true;
}
```

I get the error on this line:

```
setContentView(R.layout.about);
```

Comment: Can you provide the error log?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to start an Activity you do it with `Intents.` Intends are kind of messenger to carry our messages, requests in simply definition.

```
//This creates a new Intent object that has home and target
Intent niceIntent = new Intent(YourCurrentActivityName.this, TargetActivityName.class);

//Now start your Activity(Operation)
startActivity(niceIntent);

...
```

Above codes about our Home Activity also we must do somethings in our Target Activity.

In your Target activity's onCreate method AFTER `super.onCreate`.. you must set `setContentView(R.layout.about);` to see your about page.

### Also another important issue is about `AndroidManifest.xml`

Android system must know every change. If you add a new Activity to your application you have to inform `AndroidManifest.xml`

**How inform AndroidManifest.xml for new Activity?**

```
   <activity
        android:name="com.yourpackagename.projectname"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```